# How to hide password in Tkinter

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter, password-protection

```
def lock():
    global pas,lk
    lk=Tk.Frame(main)
    lk.pack(fill="both", anchor="center", expand=1)
    Tk.Label(lk, text="", font="arial 75").pack(anchor="center", side="top")
    fpas=Tk.LabelFrame(lk, text="Zadejte heslo:")
    fpas.pack(anchor="center")
    pas=Tk.Entry(fpas)
    pas.pack()
    Tk.Button(lk, text="OK", command=check).pack(side="top")
    Tk.Button(lk, text="Vypnout", command=lkend).pack(side="top")
    return
```

This is a part of my code and I want to change it. When I write my password into `Tk.Entry` called `pas`, I don´t want to see numbers, but a only specific symbol, such as * or another symbol. Thanks for the answer.

P.S: Please don´t evaluate my code, I know that I can write it better, but I only ask for how to hide a password, not for my tkinter skills :-D

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just use the `show` option of the `Entry` widget:

```
pas = Tk.Entry(fpas, show='*')
```